# How to run a Metro-App from PowerShell on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Related to [another question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/q/433477/79358), I'm trying to run a Metro based application from the command-line. According to a comment on my superuser question, I could maybe find an answear on a PowerShell command or script. I already tried but found anything on any internet reference about PowerShell and Windows 8...

So, there is some specific way/command to call and run a Metro-style application from a PowerShell command on Windows 8?

Comment: [`IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903.aspx).  I'm not at all familiar with PowerShell, though.

Comment: Are you sure this works on Metro apps? "Applies to: desktop apps only"

Comment: That means that that API can only be called from a desktop app.

Comment: Hmm, sure, I will try to use it to open a metro aplication with powershel... Thank you.

Comment: You can enumerate and find registered packages via [`PackageManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager).

Comment: Did you solve it Diego? Would like to do the same..

Comment: @IrisClasson Yes, Kind of.... I answered another question made on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/q/433477/79358).

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to do this but there are a couple indirect ways.

vsdebuglaunchnotify, which comes with Visual Studio, can be called from PowerShell.

You could create your own exe that uses **IApplicationActivationManager**.

If the app is associated with any file types you could launch an associated file.

More information is covered in this thread on MSDN:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/8d1b0861-5903-4289-8cb8-541ddaa012fb

Answer (score 2):

Here's a blog post by Powertoe that uses the IApplicationActivationManager way of doing it:

http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/get-a-list-of-metro-apps-and-launch-them-in-windows-8-using-powershell/

He provides code here http://poshcode.org/3740 that provides a Start-MetroApp commandlet for powershell.

Alternatively: I think some Metro Apps have protocol handlers, so that you can talk to them via a URI (e.g. "appname:dosomething") but I'm not sure how widely used this is.