# Run Windows 8 app programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-8

Is it possible to run metro UI app programmatically from Win32 application in C# 2010?

Thank you.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: Windows 8 apps aren't standard EXE files, so normal way of running external applications by Process.Start(...) doesn't work. I would like to open a discussion and meet your experience in this area, because I know that it isn't a trivial problem currently.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 does not support the .NET 4.5 Framework and thus are unable to develop against the WinRT library.  This question needs a great more detail to make it less trivial then "can this be done" type question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a Metro-App from PowerShell on Windows 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984786/how-to-run-a-metro-app-from-powershell-on-windows-8)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to us the [IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903.aspx) interface as suggested in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984786/how-to-run-a-metro-app-from-powershell-on-windows-8)

Comment: Actually, this is a good answer... you have the interop code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925748/iapplicationactivationmanageractivateapplication-in-c