# Set win10/metro app as foreground window in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am writing automated tests to verify that my website works as expected on Microsoft's Edge browser. As a part of my testing, I need to set focus on another window, and then reset the focus back onto the Edge browser.

With other browsers, I can use **Set-WindowActive** or **SetForeGroundWindow**, but neither of those work for Edge. For example, the following code works on any other browser, but does NOT work with MS Edge:

```
$IE = Get-Process iexplore
Select-Window $IE | Set-WindowActive
```

I believe this is because other browsers are desktop applications, but Edge uses the Metro app interface instead. How can I set focus on a Metro/Win10 style app using powershell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a Metro-App from PowerShell on Windows 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984786/how-to-run-a-metro-app-from-powershell-on-windows-8)